# Is using two consecutive verbs grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

- > I **go sing** karaoke at bars.
- > An engineer **goes camping**.

The verbs **go** and **sing** and **go** and **camp** with **-ing** have been used consecutively in the above two sentences respectively. Are they grammatically correct and if they are then what do they mean?

Comment: Somewhat related: [They're going gorilla watching](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40770/theyre-going-gorilla-watching-is-there-a-verb-at-the-end-of-the-sentence)

Comment: Somewhat more related: **[How should I use “go + present participle”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6529/how-should-i-use-go-present-participle)**

Comment: And a question at ELU SE: **[What is the origin of “GO + VERB + ING”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253849/what-is-the-origin-of-go-verb-ing)**

Comment: Your title, which has two consecutively verbs as you've defined them, is not grammatical. However, this is because of "of," which doesn't belong there.

Comment: "I go sing" is not correct, although you could say "let's go sing" or "I'm going to go sing". "Goes camping" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is correct. Let me give you a few more examples using the same structure of sentence construction :

1. > *"They **go skiing** every winter."*
2. > *"**Come dance** with me."*
3. > *"**Go fetch** the newspaper."*
4. > *"He got **carried away** and bought 15 books."*

There are many more examples that are grammatically correct. So yes, you can use two verbs consecutively. But this isn't the case for all the verbs. You can't use all the verbs in this fashion.